# How to index two arrays in MongoDB? Error: cannot index parallel array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongodb-indexes

Whenever I want to insert a new document, I receive the following error: `MongoError: cannot index parallel arrays [english] [german]`

What's the proper way to work with two unique arrays in MongoDB? What are alternatives to my approach?

**My scheme:**

```
const generalWordENSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    german: {
      type: Array, 
      required: true
    },
    english: {
      type: Array, 
      required: true
    },
    partOfSpeech: {
      default: null,
      type: String
    },
    example: {
      default: null,
      type: String, 
    },
    defintion: {
      default: null,
      type: String, 
    },
    image: {
      default: null,
      type: String, 
    },
    audio: {
      default: null,
      type: String, 
    },
    level: {
      default: null,
      type: Number, 
    },
  });

  generalWordENSchema.index({ german: 1, english: 1, partOfSpeech: 1}, { unique: true })
```

**Example data:**

```
{
      "english": ["jacket"],
      "german": ["Jacke", "Jackett", "Sakko"],
      "partOfSpeech": "noun",
      "example": "My jacket is brown and has two pockets.",
      "definition": "",
      "image": "",
      "audio": "",
      "level": ""
},
```

Comment: Indexes on array fields are called as Multikey Indexes. A Compound Index (like you have defined with two array fields) is not allowed in a Multikey Index.

Comment: Damn. Does a workaround exist for it? Is there a better way to solve it than to add two more fields with the first word of each array? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Your index(es) should support the application's queries. Why do you need a compound index like that?

Comment: It's the database of my language learning app, so I want to make sure that every word exists only one time. Every word needs to be unique, so the progress per word is correct (progress is stored in another collection).

Comment: (1) A unique index on an array field doesnt impose uniqueness within the same document . The uniqueness is only applied across documents in a collection. (2) You have the option to create two separate unique indexes - one for each field (if you require it). (3) When populating or adding to an array use the `$addToSet` array update operator - this will ensure uniqueness within an array within a document.

Comment: I don't want to check this. I need to check if the combination of English array, German array, and part of speech already exists in another document. The reason for this is that I store the users' progress/strength of each word in another collection. The frequency of the word repetition is decided by the progress/strength. If there's a duplicate document I couldn't guarantee that the word gets repeated correctly because one document would show strength 0, so the word gets repeated every day, while the others strength is 4 and gets repeated every 30 days.

Comment: You can store english and german array field values within same array. The array can have sub-documents like `words`: [ { lang: "en", w: "jacket" }, "{ lang: "ge", w: "Jacke" }, ... ]. Now you can have unique compound index on the `words` + `partOfSpeech`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution would have looked more professional, but I solved it already otherwise in the meantime. The first element of each array is now working as the preferred answer to questions and also to make the unique index work.